# Texture missing

Tags: texturing

I am trying to paint my 3D objects in Blender.
However, as many of you know for some people the objects automatically become purple.
When you try and paint over it they say 'missing texture'
Many people have solved this issue by 'the find missing files' option.
I tried this and it doesn't work. I have no texture option in any of my files.
Some say I misplaced it; the reality is I never touched any of the files in order to misplace/change it.
Nonetheless, I unistalled and then reinstalled blender making sure to not mess with the files.
I straight away tried colouring a 3D object but again same issue; and again textures is missing and cannot be found anywhere.
What can I do?

Comment: If you never created a texture or linked it to the material in the first place, you won’t be able to “find” it. Do you know this?

Comment: No I did not. I thought you can just paint over objects. So I need to create a texture? How do I do that?

Comment: I’ll work on getting an explanation together…

Answer (score 1):

Every object in blender can have one or more materials. Materials are the definition of how faces will look in the render: Their color, how reflective they are, if they are transparent or emitting light, etc. An object technically can have no material associated with it, and Blender will default to showing the whole thing as a solid white. Each material an object uses will be in a material slot. You can add and remove material slots that will, and assign part or all of the object to each slot. An immediate advantage of assigning parts of the object to slots (rather than directly to materials as one might expect Blender to work) is that you can trade out materials in a particular slot, and all faces using that slot will switch to the new material. Sometimes, you will assign no part of a mesh directly to a slot, usually because a modifier is meant to use the material in the slot, such as the particle system modifier or the bevel modifier.

A texture is a map of information, usually colors or grayscale values, with a coordinate system that is independent of the Scene 3-D space. A common type of texture is an image texture, and a common way of mapping that image texture onto the 3-D object is UV maps. UV has nothing to do with ultraviolet in this case, and is simply a reference to the horizontal and vertical axis of the image texture. If the 3-D coordinate system wasn’t already using XYZ, we would probably use X and Y for the image coordinates instead of U and V. So, quite simply, a UV map is an “unwrapping” of the mesh into the two-dimensional image coordinate system.

Another type of texture is a procedural texture. These are textures generated from formulas by the 3-D software on the fly, and thus are infinite and can have any number of axes. You can still use UV maps to map them onto the object, but often other coordinates will do, or are desirable (such as Generated, Object, Reflection, etc).

While it is the most common case, a texture does not necessarily define an object’s color. It can define any number of properties of the material that vary over the object surface, such as roughness, emission, clearcoat, etc.

So, to set up a texture for basic coloring, you need to:

1. UV unwrap the mesh. Do this in the UV editing screen. You can try Smart UV project, or you can do it the old-fashioned way by selecting edges where you want the mesh to split for the unwrap, Mark as seam, then select all, and UV unwrap.
2. Create a new image texture to use. You can do this externally in an image editor program, or internally from the Texture Paint screen. Buttons for managing and creating new image data blocks are in the Image editor header.
3. Connect the new image texture to the base color of your material in the Shading screen: Add an image node, select the pulldown, and select the new image data block, then connect the Image Texture node to the shader node.
4. Hop back over to Texture Paint, and paint the object. Don’t forget to save the image data block either as a packed block or as an external file when you’re done.

For more information, see [the Blender Manual page on the subject.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/texture_paint/introduction.html)

Hope this helps! SDG.