# Two materials in one mesh

Tags: mesh, materials

I don't want two materials in one mesh. But when joining two meshes with Ctrl+j, it happened.
How can I make the object just one material?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Select the one you don't want and click the minus button to the right to delete it. This has to be done in _Object Mode_, you cannot delete materials in _Edit Mode_.

Comment: See this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275798/73575 for an explanation on how materials work.

Answer (score 1):

The object actually doesn’t have two different materials, it has two different material slots, and one of them is empty. This was probably the case for the original objects as well. The solution is simple: Delete the empty material slot (this can only be done in object mode); @Gordon Brinkmann is correct. See [this page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/assignment.html) for more info. The faces that were assigned to that slot will be reassigned to the remaining one.

Comment: I actually intentionally didn't specify to select the empty slot, since beginners sometimes do not really understand that the displayed light grey color on an object is not a material - and since one part of the object is still the default grey and the question does not mention if yellow or grey should be kept, I just left it to the OP ;) But I guess your comment with the link to the materials explanation is quite valuable for the understanding.