# How do you get the UV Mapping to show up on my texture?

Tags: uv

I'm new to Blender and was watching a tutorial on how to texture meshes, but I saw that one of the videos had the UV mapping showing when they were painting the mesh, but I can't seen to get the mapping to show up. How do I do it?[image]

Comment: When you create a new Image, you can choose a color grid or a UV grid, maybe that's what you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Texture missing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275790/texture-missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your object, switch to *Edit* mode, select all, it should display the UVs in the *Image Editor*.