# Selection by specified object

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, objects, edit-mode

How to select many objects using another object either by projection or intersection, but not by sectioning along the projection because it spoils the mesh? Is there a way to select using volume so that all objects that are inside the main one are selected?
The result should look like in picture 3, but I did this manually, since the example is simple.
I repeat once again, the selection should be due to another object or the projection of another object, or at the expense of volume,if possible.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] link below your post, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Comment: I am going to edit this to one question, the bigger one about selecting stuff. As for texture painting, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275798/73575 for a brief rundown on how that works. As for vector graphics, there is a bundled addon you can enable that will let you import SVG graphics as paths, but Blender can’t currently use SVG files as image textures directly, so you’ll have to raster them to a PNG or such.